# How to replace using patsubst Makefile?

Tags: makefile, wildcard, gnu-make, gnu

I have a makefile somewhat like this.
I need to generate a file and move that as abc.cpp (Basically get rid of anything after underscore including underscore

```
xyz:= abc_def

$(xyz):
       (some commands here which generates a file)

       mv file /tmp/$(patsubst _%,"",$@) 
       
       However this does not work. In fact it doesn't ever match the underscore "_" in $@
       
       mv file /tmp/abc.cpp is what i want
```

How does the "%" wildcard work in patsusbst?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `patsubst` function won't work for you, because it can match only ONE pattern.  You want to match two patterns: anything before the `_` and anything after the `_`.  `$(patsubst _%,...)` only matches words that *begin* with `_`, and your word `abc_def` doesn't begin with `_`, so the `patsubst` is a no-op.

To do what you want using GNU make functions you need to play a trick; something like:

```
mv file /tmp/$(firstword $(subst _, ,$@))
```

This splits the string into words by changing the `_` to space, then takes the first word.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't shy away from using helper code (i.e. include a `GNUmake` library) then [the GNUmake table toolkit](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) surely can do the trick:

```
include gmtt.mk

xyz:= abc_def

$(xyz):
   (some commands here which generates a file)

   mv file /tmp/$(firstword $(call glob-match,$@,*_*)).cpp
```

The `glob-match` function splits a string in streaks of matching elements, where every glob character (`*`,`?`,`[...]`) and verbatim string portions (in your case just the `_`) constitute one match. Or simply said, `$(call glob-match,this_is_a_string,*_is_a_*)` splits `this_is_a_string` into a list `this  _is_a_  string` (notice the spaces).